# How can I create a FOREIGN KEY in SQLite?

Tags: database, sqlite

I have a table already created, here's the code:

```
CREATE TABLE "Préstamo_Biomédica" (
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
    Entregado CHAR(100),
    Fech_Pres DATE, 
    Fech_Devu DATE,
    Nota TEXT
)
```

And I'm trying to create a table with a FOREIGN KEY with this code:

```
CREATE TABLE Inventario_Biomédica (
    Id_Pieza INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Nom_Pieza CHAR(100),
    Cantidad INT,
    Des_Pieza TEXT,
    Gastable BIT,
    Fech_Ent DATE,
    P_Módulo BIT,
    FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES Préstamo_Biomédica(ID_Préstamo),
)
```

I hope you guys can help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use only ASCII characters in identifiers. If not, you must quote them.

To get an [autoincrementing](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) ID, you must use INTEGER, not INT.

The FOREIGN KEY clause refers to a column that already must exist in the table's column list.
And the parent's table/column names come after the REFERENCE:

```
CREATE TABLE "Inventario_Biomédica" (
    Id_Pieza INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    Nom_Pieza CHAR(100),
    Cantidad INT,
    Des_Pieza TEXT,
    Gastable BIT,
    Fech_Ent DATE,
    "P_Módulo" BIT,
    "ID_Préstamo" INT,
    FOREIGN KEY ("ID_Préstamo") REFERENCES "Préstamo_Biomédica"(ID),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE "Préstamo_Biomédica" (
ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
Entregado CHAR(100),
Fech_Pres DATE, 
Fech_Devu DATE,
Nota TEXT
)
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE Inventario_Biomédica (
Id_Pieza INT PRIMARY KEY,
Nom_Pieza CHAR(100),
Cantidad INT,
Des_Pieza TEXT,
Gastable BIT,
Fech_Ent DATE,
P_Módulo BIT,
FOREIGN KEY (ID_Préstamo) REFERENCES Préstamo_Biomédica(ID),
)
```

Give foreign Key Column Name right after `FOREIGN KEY` and parent tables Primary key column after `REFERENCES`

Comment: [ unknown column "ID_Préstamo" in foreign key definition ]

Comment: You must declare foreign key column as ID_Préstamo INT